# ArCore .obj FileNotFound exception

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

I am making an ArCore app and when I build my ModelRenderable I am getting this exception thrown:

```
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Coffee Cup_final.obj (No such file or directory)
        at com.google.ar.sceneform.utilities.SceneformBufferUtils.inputStreamToByteBuffer(SourceFile:49)
        at com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.LoadRenderableFromSfbTask.lambda$downloadAndProcessRenderable$0$LoadRenderableFromSfbTask(LoadRenderableFromSfbTask.java:119)
        at com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.-$$Lambda$LoadRenderableFromSfbTask$0DkaOpfpmr8DYlbaxWogZtUpKTw.get(Unknown Source:4)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1625)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Coffee Cup_final.obj (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
```

But I can see this file exists. Here is the renderable followed by build gradle.

```
ModelRenderable.builder()
                .setSource(this, Uri.parse("Coffee Cup_final.obj.obj"))
                .build()
                .thenAccept(this::onRenderableLoaded)
                .exceptionally(throwable -> {
                    Log.i("Sceneform", "failed to load model");
                    return null;
                });

sceneform.asset('sampledata/Coffee Cup_final.obj.obj',
            'default',
            'sampledata/Coffee Cup_final.obj.sfa',
            'src/main/assets/Coffee Cup_final.obj')
```

[image]

Does it have to do with the uppercase naming of my 3D object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sceneform.asset() step in build.gradle converts the OBJ file to Sceneform's internal SFB file format. So the file that's created and copied to your assets folder is src/main/assets/Coffee Cup_final.obj.sfb . So if you change

```
ModelRenderable.builder().setSource(this, Uri.parse("Coffee Cup_final.obj.obj"))
```

to

```
ModelRenderable.builder().setSource(this, Uri.parse("Coffee Cup_final.obj.sfb"))
```

it should work.

Comment: As you can see in my sampledata folder, there is no .sfb file generated automatically. So if I do what you suggested how is it going to work?

Comment: The SFB file is generated and put in the assets folder of your app. That's the last parameter of the  sceneform.assets() build step: 'src/main/assets/Coffee Cup_final.obj'. This defines the name of the SFB file (without its extension). So it will generate a file named src/main/assets/Coffee Cup_final.obj.sfb . It's described in detail here: https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/sceneform/import-assets